# Excel - Advanced Text Filters

Tags: excel, filter

I have a long list of strings:

```
"apple is red"
"apple is big"
"apple tastes yummy"
"lemon is yellow"
"lemon is big"
"lemon tastes sour"
"orange is rotten"
"watermelon is red"
```

Now I want to create a short list of filter words (way more than just 2) like:

```
"red"
"big"
```

I need an Excel fitler that can return the rows or records that DOES NOT have the words from the filter. Result should be:

```
"apple tastes yummy"
"lemon is yellow"
"lemon tastes sour"
"orange is rotten"
```

I would greatly appreciate your ideas!  I hope I can do it without using VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*this question is best asked at superuser*)

You could use a simple working column formula and then filter the TRUE results

If

1. your strings were in column A
2. your list is in B1:B10

then in C1 array enter (by pressing Shift & Ctrl & Enter) this formuls
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$1:$B$10,A1)))

Then filter column C for the FALSE results

[image]

Comment: brettdj - That was awesome.  Been using excel for years and never have I seen the Shift+Ctrl+Enter formulas until now.  You rock!  Thanks!

Comment: Thx David. You might find this information source for [array formulas](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use text to columns then apply `iserror(match(b3, r1:r10, 0))` on the word list and then apply a normal filter on the TRUE / FALSE values.

Comment: but normal text filters only allow for two strings as filters